# How to increase menu and tab font size in IntelliJ JetBrains PyCharm, PhpStorm, RubyMine

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I understand how to increase the font size within an editor tab, but I'd like to increase the font size of the main navigation menu and most importantly, the tab titles.  These do not change when I zoom in or out of an editor tab (using Cmd + mouse wheel on OSX). I do not see anything in the preferences menus.

Answer (score 245, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Appearance & Behavior | Appearance`
3. Enable `Use custom font` option -- it will allow to change font used for GUI as well override its size.

[image]

In prior IDE versions (2018.2 and older) that option was named `Override default fonts by`:

[image]

---

**P.S.** The latest 2023.1 version can now zoom the whole thing at once (editor and interface fonts as well as GUI elements): `View | Appearance | Zoom IDE`.

https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2023/03/intellij-idea-2023-1/#Userexperience

> In v2023.1 it’s possible to zoom into and out of IntelliJ IDEA entirely, increasing or decreasing the size of all UI elements at once.

[image]

Comment: In 2018.3 the option is called "Use custom font" where you can set font style and size. Same setting dialog...`Appearance & Behavior | Appearance`

Comment: This is a reminder for future me: there is an option in Editor > General > Editor Tabs window called "Use small fonts for labels". If you uncheck this, the tab font size will increase, without having to change the entire UI font.

Comment: 2021.3 macOS version is randomly making size 13 look like 8, and 14 looks like 20. Random 

Comment: Breaking news that helped me a lot here: Switch to another tab to make the changes visible!

Answer (score 17):

Update to version 2019.3

Goto `File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance`

Enable Use custom font:`Tahoma` Size:`12`

Comment: can i change its color ?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhak Goto File | Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | (PHP,CSS,HTML...)