# How to change pycharm settings when font size is too big to interact with the GUI?

Tags: pycharm

Actually I'm an idiot and I have missclicked in a hurry the size of my font size while changing the settings and I can't redo it because pycharm is not reacting as it suppose. My goal was to set it to 20 and I misstyped it to 200:).

Reinstall is not the way I want to solve this problem.
Shortcut for settings is working but settings are not, the only thing I see is gray background and they are not loading at all and I can't interact with them.
Also I don't have any files in %appdata% folder so I can't configure via that also

Here are also some screenshot of my pycharm view.

Yes I see only that little:
[image: yes i see only that little]

That's how settings inside GUI look like.:
[image: that's how settings inside gui look like.]

If anyone know how to reset or change styling settings without interacting with settings inside GUI.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The breadcrumbs to setting the font size are explained [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39216427/) provided you [minimize the window - OS specific](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/147695-how-minimize-restore-app-window-windows-10-a.html) it should be possible to revert the values. Another option is [editing the IDE's configuration files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html) easy way would be searching for `200` which is the value you set previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can navigate to the [configuration directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory), find *options/other.xml* file and edit the following component.

```xml
<component name="NotRoamableUiSettings">
    <option name="fontScale" value="1.0" />
    <option name="fontSize" value="22" /> <!-- edit this value -->
</component>
```